# ScrollView problem in Android

Tags: android, scrollview

i am creating demo app for question answer. its MCQ type test. i have set all question and answers layout in scrollview. the size of question and answers layout is change according to question and answer's content.

when i scroll for my last ans option and then load next question my question view is hide under scroll on top. i want to start scroll from top every time when my new question and answer is load.

Here is my XML :

```
 <ScrollView android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/scroll"
                android:layout_below="@+id/que_count"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip">
<RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/topbar"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/road_sign_layout">
<RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:layout_below="@+id/topbar"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/bubble1"
                android:id="@+id/que">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
              android:id="@+id/road_signs_images"/>         
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
              android:textSize="15dip"
              android:id="@+id/question"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/que"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:id="@+id/ansA"
                android:background="@drawable/ans_bg_new">            
    <TextView android:layout_width="250dip"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:minHeight="35dip"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/question"
              android:id="@+id/ans1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ansA"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:id="@+id/ansB"
                android:background="@drawable/ans_bg_new">            
    <TextView android:layout_width="250dip"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:minHeight="35dip"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_below="@+id/ans1"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:id="@+id/ans2"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ansB"
                android:id="@+id/ansC"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:background="@drawable/ans_bg_new">            
    <TextView android:layout_width="250dip"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:textColor="#000000" 
              android:minHeight="35dip"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_below="@+id/ans2"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:id="@+id/ans3"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ansC"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:background="@drawable/ans_bg_new"
                android:id="@+id/ansD">           
    <TextView android:layout_width="250dip"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_below="@+id/ans3"
              android:textColor="#000000" 
              android:minHeight="35dip"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:id="@+id/ans4"/>

 </RelativeLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

any suggetion?

Thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this code.

Write the code after the code of loading new question.

```
chatScrollView.post(new Runnable() 
        { 
            public void run() { 
                chatScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UPs); 
            } 
        });
```

Let me know it's working or not ?

Comment: Hello Piyush... I am not Bipul ... I am Bipin...
Please, Write the right name....

Answer (score 0):

you can put only one layout under `scrollview` not the nested layout as you have used..remove the inner layout ..

refer this doc:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html